# Getting Issues with trying to pass params to knockout function from view on click

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So consider the following:

```
<!-- ko foreach: new Array($root.totalPages()) -->
  <!-- ko if: $index() + 1 === $root.currentPage() -->
  <li class="active"><a href="#" data-bind="text: $index() + 1"></a></li>
  <!-- /ko -->

  <!-- ko if: $index() + 1 !== $root.currentPage() -->
  <li><a href="#" data-bind="click: $root.navigateToPageNum.bind($index() + 1), text: $index() + 1"></a></li>
  <!-- /ko -->
<!-- /ko -->
```

The important piece is the `click: $root.navigateToPageNum.bind($index() + 1), ...`

The issue is when I throw a `console.log` in said function, I get undefined.

```
    self.navigateToPageNum = function(pageNumber) {
      console.log(pageNumber);
    }
```

This gives me undefined which I click on the `li` link element.

The `totalPages()` is 7, so I do have 7 `li` links on the page. but clicking on one gives me undefined.

**How can I pass the current index to the function?**

Answer (score 1):

The [first parameter of `bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is the `thisArg` so the current page number will be set as the `this` in your function:

```
self.navigateToPageNum = function() {
  console.log(this); // will print the page number
}
```

If you want to keep your signature you need to pass in `$index() + 1` as the second parameter to `bind`:

```
click: $root.navigateToPageNum.bind($data, $index() + 1)
```

Note: if you don't care about the `this` in the `navigateToPageNum` you can also pass in null as the first argument to `bind`.